# How to call a function immediately

Tags: reactjs

I write my request in my parent Component with code below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // my request
}, [])
```

As we all know, useEffect of parent component will implement after child component, so this request will be implemented after all child components rendered.
How can I call my request immediately before my child component's useEffect?

Comment: Your logic should not be tight to render cycles, this will eventually leads to issues down the road...

Answer (score 2):

The order of execution of useEffect in a simple parent child component like this

```
<Parent>
  <Child /> 
</Parent>
```

is, child useEffect first and then parent's.

If you want child to wait for parent's useEffect, you can use a conditional to show something else till then:

```
const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  /* other activies */
  setShowChild(true);
});

return (
  <>
    <otherСomponents />
    {showChild && <Child />
    <otherСomponents / >
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, put statement of parent `useEffect` to top of child component's `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put you function into useEffect, just in the component body:

```
export default function YourComponent() {
    // Your logic here
    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

Because your component is just a function too, your function will be called immediately.